# Jenkins Separate Email for Each Module?

Tags: maven, jenkins, multi-module, email-notifications

I have maven project with [flat structure](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/examples/multi-module-projects.html). And the parent pom partially looks like this.

```
....
<modules>
     <module>../module1</module>
     <module>../module2</module>
</modules>
....
```

**Problem**

Till now I used to have one job and send one notification email only for the parent project. And this parent project builds all the modules. But now the modules increased and became too many to be handled by one person.

**Question**

I need to send a separate notification emails for each module without creating addition jobs for the modules.

Comment: I tried configuring the default email notification for each modules but after triggering a new build all the configuration will be lost.

Comment: Why do you have a flat structure? It looks like the sturcture is not flat? For what purpose do you need to send emails ?

Comment: @khmarbaise According to the documentation I think this is a flat structure.And the emails are for notification purpose(like build failure...)

Comment: There is no relation to the structure and the mail configuration.

Comment: please explain more

Comment: If you build a multi module structure in Maven you have usually only a single Job for that...which means those modules will be build inside a single Jenkins job. In consequence you have only a single mail configuration.

Comment: @khmarbaise exactly!!!but now I want to send different mails for each modules.what i mean is if module1 build fails i'll send an email to person1.and module2 fails to person2...

Comment: Configurate the mail to use culprits and that will do what you need...(May be you need to install ext-mail plugin in jenkins.